# Git repository corruption

Tags: git, cygwin, corruption, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a local git repository on my filesystem. I'm working against the master -- which is probably not a good idea -- and there are no other clones or backups, etc. All of a sudden, when I try to commit, I get error messages. They're often different, but they've settled on something like:

```
error: invalid object 040000 [hash] for '[path]'
error: Error building trees
```

This is under 1.7.9 in Cygwin. If I do `git fsck`, I get a lot of dangling commit, blob and tree messages (n.b., the dangling tree hash matches the invalid object hash, FWIW).

If, however, I use the embedded git in Atlassian SourceTree (git 1.8.3), I can commit just fine.

Any ideas on what I can do to fix the corruption?

Comment: Update the standalone version of git to 1.8 (or 1.9) ?

Comment: 1.7.9 is packaged with Cygwin, so I would have to compile a later version from source. If that will solve the problem, I'll consider it...

Comment: Why don't install a prepackaged version from http://git-scm.com/download/win ? It works for me :)

Comment: "Windows git" doesn't play nice with Cygwin :(

Comment: First of all, make a full copy of your repository (working directory and all), futzing around might damage it even more. If you have a copy of your project at atalassian, get a fresh clone from there and see if anything is amiss. Digging into the respective files under `.git` *might* help repair the original, or at least allow to rescue lost commits that weren't commited remotely. Note that is brain surgery on your repo...